# Faster playback in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

When I edit videos in the VSE, I would like to have a fast preview (e.g. sped up 1.5 times). Is it possible to adjust the speed of the playhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to speed up the overall frames pr. sec. you can do this in the Properties - Output - Frame Rate.

If you just want faster search through the video, two add-ons support this: Power Sequencer(included in Blender, but needs to be enabled in Preferences) or VSEQF: https://github.com/snuq/VSEQF

If you want to only speed up one strip, this can be done by adding a Speed Effect Strip.

Comment: Wow, thanks!! Power Sequencer and VSEQF seem *extremely* promising!!! They even offer ripple-delete which I was already about to program myself xD